# NAT failed when DirectAccess Enabled

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, nat

I have this topology:

[image: topology]

I have 192.168.1.0/24 as private network, 20.1.1.0/24 and 100.1.1.0/24 as Public Network.
WinDC is the Domain Controller and Winrtr is Router.
The ISP act as outside DNS and Routing.
At first, I only config RRAS with NAT and routing options.
It works fine, Winclt can ping and reach WinDC and ISP.

But when I enable the DirectAccess, the NAT seems failed. Winclt can't reach WinDC and ISP. Of course, I can't reach outside network.
Any Ideas?
My goal is to config WinRTR as DirectAccess Server and NAT Router.

Comment: Is ipv6 set to the defaults?

Comment: Yes. I set IPv6 to default and I didn't config any IP address with it.